# python - Value error : I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am very new to Python.

I am creating a script that I can run that will process an XLSX file and convert it into a pipe "|" delimited csv. Thankfully, I've figured this piece out. However, I am trying to add an extra step - I'd like the same script to remove any commas in my file. I thought I had it, however, I get the following error message: **Value error : I/O operation on closed file**. From what I can tell, I may have indentation issues, but I can't figure out where. I've tried several combinations. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

data_xls = pd.read_excel('Chartwell.xlsx', 'Chartwell', index = False)
data_xls.to_csv('your_csv2.csv', index = False, sep='|', encoding='utf-8')

input_file = open('your_csv2.csv', 'r')
output_file = open('No_Commas.csv', 'w')
for line in input_file:
    line = line.replace(",", " ")
    output_file.write(line)
    output_file.close()
    input_file.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly it. (Basically you were closing the files on your first pass through the `for` iteration.) Try this alteration:

```
input_file = open('your_csv2.csv', 'r')
output_file = open('No_Commas.csv', 'w')
for line in input_file:
    line = line.replace(",", " ")
    output_file.write(line)
output_file.close()
input_file.close()
```

Even better, if you have a more recent version of Python, you can use a `with` block that will automatically close the file when you leave the scope:

```
with open('your_csv2.csv', 'r') as f:
    input_file = f.readlines()
with open('No_Commas.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        line = line.replace(",", " ")
        output_file.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you Alec! That was exactly what I needed.